# Several boxes are animated (translated) asynchronously

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions, css-animations

**Description:**

The page consists of three main boxes: header at the top, menu at the right and content area.

Header and menu have to be with property `position: fixed`

Initially menu is hidden on the page. It appears when user clicks e.g. on a specific button.

When it's appearing it's sliding from the right to the left. At the same time header and content pushed to the left.

**Solution based on:**

Using CSS3 properties `transform` with `translate3d` values and `transition: transform 0.5s linear`

**The problem**

During animation between menu and content with header boxes we can see blinking white area. Playing with backface-visibility didn't help.

**JSFiddle**

Here is an example online: http://jsfiddle.net/milax/5uc7or6r/6/

**Browser**

Chrome 39

What might be caused that? What's done wrong... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below:

```
.site-wrapper div {
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid transparent; /* <--- fixes horrible anti-aliasing */
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uc7or6r/10/)

Comment: No, it doesn't help, the same behavior. I've found the solution, plz see my answer.

Comment: Hmmm in Version 39.0.2171.65 m of Chrome the above works, so will leave in case it helps anyone down the line.

Comment: I use Version 39.0.2171.65 m, absolutely the same :)
May be it also depends on computer's performance.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed.**

The problem was in using percents instead of pixels for the property `translate3d`. So,

`transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);`

must be changed to

`transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);`

Of course, if you know a width of menu exactly.